# Search with relations eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to search users by ($_POST['search'] '"name" and "lastname"') that follows the

> "user id = 1"

I got the table users, in users I got

> "name" and "lastname"

And I got the table followers, in followers I got

> "follower_id" and "user_id"...

I know that to  do it I have to use models related, but I don't know how...

```
//$user_id = 1 (in followers.user_id)
//$_POST['search'] (in users.name and users.lastname)

public function u_followers_search($user_id) {

$followers = ...

return $followers;

}
```

Comment: Take a look at this [article](https://medium.com/innohub/create-user-following-system-with-laravel-5-4-5fc47828fb39) !

Comment: do you already have the relations?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a relationship on your `User` model:

```
function followers() {
    return $this->hasMany(Follower::class)
}
```

This will enable you to do:

```
$userId = 1 // or however you get the user id
$user = User::findOrFail($userId)->followers;
```

**EDIT:**

With the relationship it means you will be able to get all the followers that follow a specific user:

```
$allFollowers = User::findOrFail($userId)->followers;
```

This will give you all Users that follow User with id 1

You can then continue the query and add your matching criteria

```
$allFollowers->where('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
             ->orWhere('lastname', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
             ->get();
```

This will filter all the followers of User with id 1 and only get the followers that have the search query in their `name` or `lastname`

**EDIT 2:**

For the above to work you need relationships set up both ways:

`User` model:

```
function followers() {
    return $this->hasMany(Follower::class)
}
```

`Follower` model:

```
function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class)
}
```

This will enable you to get the followers for a specified user

Comment: But I want search by name and lastname with the $_POST['search'], the ID is the ID of the user that is followed...

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to search for a `User` who matches a `name` and `lastname` and get their followers?

Comment: @ValterSousaCardoso is the edit what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: this line will only get the followers of user 1: `$allFollowers = User::findOrFail($userId)->followers;` then you can refine that list using the query after to get only the followers who match the search query